# return redirect()->route with request not parameter in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I have a function with the name of Direction which takes the request and redirects to the following view if the condition is true. here is the code

```
   public function direction(Request $request)
{
    $activity_id=$request->id;
    $activity_type=Activity::where('id',$activity_id)->pluck('type');
    if($activity_type[0]=='event')
     {

     return redirect()->route('getActivity',compact('activity_id'));
     }
    
    else{
         echo "please select valid id ";
     }
}
```

it works perfectly, but I like to use the same function after saving some data in another table. and redirect to the following I use

```
return  redirect()->route('progress.direction',$activity_id)->with('message','Save Successfully!');
```

it redirects the only parameter `http://localhost:8000/progress/direction?1ac27656-0da2-4dc7-a3f9-3604e002db91` which not get as request.
my question is how to send the following parameter as a request from the controller.

Comment: can you show progress.direction route

Comment: Route::post('/progress/direction','ProgressReportController@direction')->name('progress.direction');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your routes like below

```
Route::any('/progress/direction/{direction?}','ProgressReportController@direction')->name('progress.direction');
```

here i have added question mark it means its optional .if you not needed optional then you can remove question mark

Comment: after saving data how to redirect the return  redirect()->route('progress.direction',$activity_id)->with('message','Save Successfully!'); i use compact like compact('activity_id') it is same show the http://localhost:8000/progress/direction?1ac27656-0da2-4dc7-a3f9-3604e002db91

Comment: try  return redirect()->route('progress.direction',$activity_id)->with('message','Save Successfully!');

Comment: i use the direction function twice first , it works after saving data i want to redirect it does not show

Comment: Error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: @ismailkhan method should be get while redirecting.if you want both get and post then you can use any or match